# convert data frame of "missed" numbers into data frame of numbers "hit"

Tags: r, dataframe

I have quite an specific doubt, but it should be easy to solve, I just cannot think how...

I have a simple data frame like this:

```
mydf <- data.frame(Shooter=1:3, Targets.missed=c(paste(sample(1:10,4),collapse=";"), paste(sample(1:10,5),collapse=";"), paste(sample(1:10,8),collapse=";")))
mydf
  Shooter   Targets.missed
1       1          3;8;4;7
2       2       10;1;5;7;4
3       3 5;9;4;10;8;1;6;7
```

This data frame tells me the `Targets` (from 1 to 10) that are missed by each `Shooter`.

I would like to obtain a different data frame that tells me, per `Target`, which `Shooter`\s made it.

The result would be:

```
Target   hit.by.Shooters
1        1
2        1;2;3
3        2;3
4        NA
5        1
6        1;2
7        NA
8        2
9        1;2
10       1
```

Comment: Let me Edit for `target` and `shooter` so it's easier to interpret

Comment: Perhaps `library(dplyr); mydf %>% separate_rows(misses) %>% group_by(Number = misses) %>% summarise(ID = paste(unique(ID), collapse=";"))`

Comment: See the edit just in case; mind that we are looking at opposite things... in the first data frame is targets missed, in the second I want to look at targets hit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We expand the data by splitting at the `;` of the 'Targets.missed' into 'long' format, then grouped by 'Shooter', `summarise` with a `list` of numbers that are not in the 'Targets.missed' from 1:10, `unnest` the `list` column, grouped by 'Target', `summarise` by `paste`ing the `unique` 'Shooter' elements into a single string, and fill the missing elements from 1:10 with `NA` by using `complete`

```
library(tidyverse)
mydf %>% 
   separate_rows(Targets.missed) %>% 
   group_by(Shooter) %>%
   summarise(Target = list(setdiff(1:10, Targets.missed))) %>% 
   unnest %>% 
   group_by(Target) %>%
   summarise(hit.by.Shooters = paste(unique(Shooter), collapse=";")) %>% 
   complete(Target = 1:10) 
# A tibble: 10 x 2
#   Target hit.by.Shooters
#    <int> <chr>          
# 1      1 1              
# 2      2 1;2;3          
# 3      3 2;3            
# 4      4 <NA>           
# 5      5 1              
# 6      6 1;2            
# 7      7 <NA>           
# 8      8 2              
# 9      9 1;2            
#10     10 1
```

---

Or another option is `base R` by splitting the 'Targets.missed' (assuming `character` class) into a `list` of `vector`s, loop through the `list`, get the values that are not in 1:10 (with `setdiff`), set the names of the `list` with the 'Shooter' column, `stack` the key/val `list` pairs into a two column data.frame, get the `unique` rows, `aggregate` by `paste`ing the 'ind' column grouped by 'values', `merge` with a full 'values' dataset from 1:10

```
out <-  aggregate(ind ~ values, 
  unique(stack(setNames(lapply(strsplit(mydf$Targets.missed, ';'), 
    setdiff, x= 1:10), mydf$Shooter))), FUN = paste, collapse=";")
out1 <- merge(data.frame(values = 1:10), out, all.x = TRUE)
```

and change the column names if necessary

```
names(out1) <- c('Target', 'hit.by.Shooters')
```

#### data

```
mydf <- structure(list(Shooter = 1:3, Targets.missed = c("3;8;4;7", "10;1;5;7;4", 
 "5;9;4;10;8;1;6;7")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
 "2", "3"))
```

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` approach

```
library( data.table )

#vector with all possible targets
targets.v <- 1:10
#split the missed targets to a list
missed.list <- strsplit( mydf$Targets.missed, ";")
#inverse, to get all hit targets
hit.list <- lapply( missed.list, function(x) as.data.table( targets.v[!targets.v %in% x] )  )
#bind hit targets to data.table
dt <- rbindlist( hit.list, idcol = "shooter" )
#summarise (paste with collapse), and join on all possible targets
dt[, .(hit.by.shooters = paste(shooter, collapse = ";")), by = .(target = V1)][data.table(target = targets.v), on = c("target")]
#     target hit.by.shooters
#  1:      1               1
#  2:      2           1;2;3
#  3:      3             2;3
#  4:      4            <NA>
#  5:      5               1
#  6:      6             1;2
#  7:      7            <NA>
#  8:      8               2
#  9:      9             1;2
# 10:     10               1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `tidyverse` possibility. We first create dataframe with all possible combinations of `Shooter` and `Targets` and then remove rows which are present in `mydf` using `anti_join`, fill in the missing `Targets` by adding them as `NA` and finally summarise by `Targets` to get `Shooters` who actually hit the target.

```
library(tidyverse)

crossing(Shooter = unique(mydf$Shooter), Targets.missed = 1:10) %>%
anti_join(mydf %>% separate_rows(Targets.missed) %>% mutate_all(as.numeric)) %>%
        complete(Targets.missed = 1:10) %>%
        group_by(Targets.missed) %>%
        summarise(hit.by.Shooters = paste0(Shooter, collapse = ";"))


# Targets.missed hit.by.Shooters
#            <int> <chr>          
# 1              1 1;2            
# 2              2 1;2            
# 3              3 1              
# 4              4 1              
# 5              5 2              
# 6              6 1;3            
# 7              7 1;2            
# 8              8 2              
# 9              9 NA             
#10             10 3
```

**data**

```
set.seed(987)
mydf <- data.frame(Shooter=1:3, 
        Targets.missed=c(paste(sample(1:10,4),collapse=";"), 
        paste(sample(1:10,5),collapse=";"), paste(sample(1:10,8),collapse=";")))
```